# How do I add a note after the List of Figures heading?

Tags: tocloft

I'm looking to add a note after my List of Figures heading, but before the actual list. The desired output would be:

### List of Figures

A short note about image credits.

2.1 Figure
3.4 Figure
3.5 Figure
...

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 


\listoffigures



\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-golden}
\caption{\label{mylabel}
A lovely box.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full but minimal self contained example shuch that others can test your code and play with it as is. `tocloft` does seem to provide hooks to add this sort of information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tocloft` does support hooks like this

```
\renewcommand\cftlofprehook{A short note about image credits.\par\medskip}
```

See `\cftZprehook` in the manual. The `...prehook` is execuited right before the list and `...posthook` right after it.

Comment: Do I need to import a package? I'm getting command undefined. Also added an MWE if that helps.

Comment: OK, figured out to \usepackage{tocloft} and it does work, though now I don't get a page break before my figures. But I can put that back in manually.

Comment: @T.Arboreus  I thought you mentioned you were alrady using `tocloft`, now you see why we always ask for code. There are normally no forced page break before LOF and friends.

Comment: Yes, should have provided one initially. Thanks for the help, ,my lof is looking spiffy.